# Do I need putting flags into synchronized blocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I had a code like this:

```
if(!flag) {
   synchronized(lock) {
     lock.wait(1000);
   }
}
if(!flag) { print("Error flag not set!"); }
```

And:

```
void f() {
   flag = true;
   synchronized(lock) {
      lock.notify()
   }
}
```

A friend of mine told me I should put flag = true inside the synchronized block:

```
  synchronized(lock) {
      flag = true;
      lock.notify()
   }
```

I do not understand why. Is it some classic example? Could someone, please, explain?

If I declare my flag volatile I then do not need putting it into the synchronized block?

Comment: Not only that, but the first code snippet should always hold the lock while it checks the flag.

Comment: adding to above comment, `wait` should be in `while` loop

Comment: I suggest you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) to see the canonical pattern that you should use with `wait`.

Comment: @assylias The javadoc you have referred to doesn't answer the question though. Anyway I got it volatile is enough in that case. So when my friend went this thread stops and that thread starts etc he was talkiking nonsense, he never mentioned volatile

Comment: @Alex marking flag volatile is not enough. you still need to use a while loop: `while(!flag) { synchronized(lock) {lock.wait();} }` (because `wait` could wakeup even if you don't call `notify`) - and since you do need to enter a synchronized block, you might as well remove the volatile keyword and include the `while` in the synchronized block: `synchronized(lock) { while(!flag) lock.wait(); }` which is exactly the code proposed in the javadoc.

Comment: @assylias But.. I want to wait only for 1 second... How to be?

Comment: With your construct, you might wakeup less than a second after you start sleeping. To sleep up to exactly one second, you would need to keep track of the time when you first start waiting and adjust the timeout accordingly at each iteration. Alternatively, you could have a look at CountdownLatch/CyclicBarrier/Semaphore which are easier to use that the low level wait/notify operations.

Answer (score 4):

Main memory is slow. Really slow. The internal cache in your CPU today is about 1000 times faster. For this reason, modern code tries to keep as much data as possible in the CPU's cache.

One of the reasons why main memory is so slow is that it's shared. When you update the main memory, all CPU cores are notified of the change. Caches, on the other hand, are per core. That means when thread A updates the flag, it just updates its own cache. Other threads might or might not see the change.

There are two ways to ensure the flag is written to main memory:

1. Put it in a `synchronized` block
2. Declare it `volatile`

`volatile` has the advantage that any access to the flag will make sure the state of the flag in main memory is updated. Use this when you use the flag in many places.

In your case, you already have the `synchronized` block. But in the first case, the first `if` might be reading a stale value (i.e. the thread might `wait()` even though the flag is already `true`). So you still need `volatile`.

Comment: @Alex Yes, it ensures proper synchronization

Answer (score 3):

As `flag` variable is used by multiple threads, some mechanism to ensure changes visibility must be used. This is indeed a common pattern in multithreading in general. Java memory model does not otherwise guarantee the other thread will ever see the new value of `flag`.

This is to allow optimizations employed by modern multiprocessor systems, where maintaining cache coherency at all times may be to costly. Memory access is usually orders of magnitute slower than other "usual" CPU operations, so modern processors go to really great lengths avoid it as much as possible. Instead, frequently accessed locations are kept in small, fast, local processor memory - a cache. Changes are only done to the cache, and *flushed* to the main memory at certain points. This works fine for one processor, as the memory content is not being changed by other parties, so we are guaranteed cache content reflects memory content. (Well, that's an oversimplification, but from high-level's programming point of view irrelevant, I believe). The problem is, as soon as we add another processor, independently changing the memory contents, this guarantee is lost. To mitigate this problem, various (sometimes elaborate - see e.g. [here](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/theses/michael_marty_phd.pdf)) **cache coherency protocols** were devised. Unsurprisingly, they require some bookkeeping and interprocessor communication overhead, though.

Other, somewhat related issue is **atomicity** of write operations. Basically, even if the change is seen by other threads, it may be seen *partially*. This is not usually so much of a problem in java, as the language specification guarantees atomicity of all writes. Still, writes to 64-bit primitives (`long` and `double`) are explicitly said to be treated as two separate, 32-bit writes:

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write. ([JLS 17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7))

Back to the code in question... synchronization is required, and `synchronized` block satisfies the need. Still, I find making the flags like that `volatile` more pleasant solution. Net effect is the same - visibility guarantee and atomic write - but it doesn't clutter the code with small `synchronized` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking and modifying the flag from different threads, it nees to be at least declared `volatile`, for threads to see the changes.

Putting the checks in synchronized blocks would work too.

And yes, it is a very basic thing in concurrency, so you should make sure you read up on the memory model, `happens-before` and other related subjects.

Comment: so my friend he was talking about stale cached values or was he assuming there is some problem even if the values are never stale?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the lock.wait(1000) will return after a second even if the other thread did not send notify.

Secondly: your friend is right, in this case you have shared data accessed by different threads so acces to it should better be guarded with a lock like in your code.

Thirdly: mark your flag variable as volatile so different threads make sure they are always using the last "written" value

And finally: I would also put the if (!flag) code in a synchronized block -> it is also accessing the flag variable...

Comment: If I make the flag volatile do I still need to put it into synchronized block?

Comment: @Alex: No, one of them is enough.